# How can I switch between views programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have the following problem. I want to go from a view to another view, not with a button, but writing code. I have a view in which there are, among other things, some buttons. When I press one of them runs an if - else. From else I want to go to another view.

I have tried this

```
GameOverViewController *gOver = [[GameOverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GameOverViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view removeFromSuperview];
gOver.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:gOver animated:YES];
```

this

```
GameOverViewController *gOver = [[GameOverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GameOverViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view insertSubview:gOver.view atIndex:0];
```

and this

```
GameOverViewController *gOver = [[GameOverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GameOverViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:gOver.view];
```

but nothing worked. Any ideas ?

i also tried this

```
GameOverViewController *gOver = [[GameOverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GameOverViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view setHidden:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gOver animated:NO];
```

throws exeption on

```
[self presentModalViewController:gOver animated:YES];

[self.view insertSubview:gOver.view atIndex:0];

[self.view addSubview:gOver.view];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: presentModelViewController should work. I am just a bit courious whether you can use [self presentModalViewController] after self.view has been removed from its superview. Why do you do that? When you want to get rid of self as a view controller, then you should dismiss it accordingly. At the appropriate place, where you dismiss the current view controller there you should present the new one - only if you really need to avoid stacking the two view controllers.

Comment: Shouldn't you, instead of adding a subview to a view that has been removed from it superview (this is a bit weird, but anyway) just replace the view with your gOver.view?

Answer (score 1):

Don´t call `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` which may cause your viewController to be deallocated, when using `presentModalViewController` it covers your view:

```
GameOverViewController *gOver = [[GameOverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GameOverViewController" bundle:nil];

// gOver.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:gOver animated:YES];
```

If you need to hide your current view then use: `[self.view setHidden: YES];`

Comment: throws exception on
[self presentModalViewController:gOver animated:YES];

Comment: Then comment out the line: // gOver.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

Comment: Nothing changed. Again throws exception.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Panosbt/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/8F6B9094-C8EA-42E5-BB6B-B0D07B105DCF/Millionaire 2012.app> (loaded)' with name 'GameOverViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13df022 0x1570cd6 ... 0x1387a48  0x29a5)
terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

"I want to go from a view to another view, not with a button, but writing code." - did you refer this to push in storyboard or did you mean that you din't want it in a button action?

The above code works fine :

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
GameViewController *game = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];
game.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl ;
[self presentModalViewController:game animated:YES];
}
```

And hope that you doing n iPhone app and not an iPad one, in which case you need to use popOver instead of modalView

Comment: I dont want button action. I just need some code inside my if - else to do the button's job.

Comment: can you just post the code you've used to implement that? just so that I can see how exactly you're trying to get this done